# WebStorm 11 freezes on Go To Declaration action for Typescript interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I'm currently using WebStorm 11 on a very large NodeJS/Typescript project and when using the "Go To -> Declaration" shortcut, my WebStorm completely freezes and has to be killed and restarted manually.

Do any of you guys encounter similar behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like you should [open a bug on their issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB).

Comment: agreed with @MadaraUchiha, WebStorm is commercial software, so they'll quickly look into that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone just came here looking for solution of WebStorm / PHPStorm freeze, I am giving my 2c.

- Make sure you are using the latest release of the IDE. The current version number shows up during its startup. If using older one, download the latest, and install it.
- Now, if the freezing problem persists with opening the project, find the `.idea` folder inside the concern project folder, and delete the .idea folder. It may stay hidden depending on your file-viewer's settings. Enable hidden-file view, if needed.
  **Caution**: This will reset your project-specific IDE settings, however general, non-projectwise settings will remain intact.